# When should a 'watcher' be used over an 'event'?

Tags: vue.js

I'm under the impression that watchers should be used as a last resort in Vue. I know that computed properties are favoured over watchers. However, there are times when you can use a watcher or an @change to do the same thing. I feel like an event is a better and more explicit way of performing an operation in the following case:

From [VueJS Guide - Computed Properties and Watchers](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers)

```
<div id="watch-example">
  <p>
    Ask a yes/no question:
    <input v-model="question">
  </p>
  <p>{{ answer }}</p>
</div>
```

```
var watchExampleVM = new Vue({
  el: '#watch-example',
  data: {
    question: '',
    answer: 'I cannot give you an answer until you ask a question!'
  },
  watch: {
    // whenever question changes, this function will run
    question: function (newQuestion, oldQuestion) {
      this.answer = 'Waiting for you to stop typing...'
      _.debounce(this.getAnswer, 500)
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

or you could do this with an @change or @input event like this:

```
<div id="watch-example">
  <p>
    Ask a yes/no question:
    <input v-model="question" @change="getAnswer">
  </p>
  <p>{{ answer }}</p>
</div>
```

```
var watchExampleVM = new Vue({
  el: '#watch-example',
  data: {
    question: '',
    answer: 'I cannot give you an answer until you ask a question!'
  },
  methods: {
    // whenever question changes, this function will run
    getAnswer: function (newQuestion, oldQuestion) {
      this.answer = 'Waiting for you to stop typing...'
      _.debounce(this.getAnswer, 500)
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

I'm not sure why a watcher would be used here over an @change or similar event. I feel that it's better to use an event in this case because it is more explicit.

So my questions are:

1. Am I performing the operation inefficiently in the second example?
2. What are the drawbacks to using an event if there are any?
3. What are the drawbacks to using a watcher here if there are any?
4. The [guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) I'm referencing in the first example states watchers are "useful when you want to perform asynchronous or expensive operations in response to changing data", however can one not just use an event and an async method to perform the asynchronous operations?

Comment: Sometimes watchers are used in cases where component props get updated (which obviously can't have an event referenced..).
I'd say: 1. no 2. none 3. it's kind of magic and a bit memory intensive 4. depends on the case (as said component props for example)
I'd always use events over watchers, maybe someone can explain it more clear and technically more correct, this is why I post this as comment.